why alert window is not displayed
my alert code-
//alerts
a1 = ta.crossover(close, h)
a2 = ta.crossunder(close, l)

if a1
    alert("BUY CALL (Price above buy level " + str.tostring(h, "#.00)"), freq = alert.freq_all)

if a2
    alert("BUY PUT  (Price below sell level " + str.tostring(l, "#.00)"), freq = alert.freq_all)

h is high of first 5 min bar.
I am expecting that alert message to be shown in Trading View, but not displayed.

Please share at least how h and l are calculated. Preferably a minimal reproducible example.

h= high  is the high of the first 5 min bar and l is the low of the same bar

[h,l] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,[high,low])
